# ProcessBuilder not executing command with wildcard

Tags: java, unix, wildcard, processbuilder

I am trying to write an utility java program that calls a perl script in unix box and shows the output of the script. The issue is when I am executing `command2`,

`String[] command2 = {"/archive/scripts/grep.pl", "/apps/ws/logs/api.log"};`

the output is coming correctly. But when i am using `command1`,

`String[] command1 = {"/archive/scripts/grep.pl", "/apps/ws/logs/*"};`

i am getting the below exception:

`Can't open /apps/ws/logs/*: No such file or directory at /archive/scripts/grep.pl line 160.`

Below is the full code for your reference:

```
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command1);
        LOGGER.debug("Command: "+processBuilder.command());
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br;
        if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
            LOGGER.debug("Inside if block. Exit value: "+process.exitValue());
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Inside Else block. Exit value: "+process.exitValue());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Exception thrown"+e.getStackTrace());
        output.append(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
```

I am not able to understand what is the issue. Is there any way to accomplish this.

Comment: Is there a file with the name of `*` in that directory? Filemasks are resolved by shells. If you execute a script directly, the shell is left out...

Comment: there is no file by the name `*`. When i run the command `/archive/scripts/grep.pl /apps/ws/logs/*` in the box, i get proper output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a command shell to interpret the wildcard

```
String[] command1 = {"bash", "-c", "/archive/scripts/grep.pl /apps/ws/logs/*"};
```

Comment: @Reimus Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the code you suggested. However, I am not getting the expected output. Though the error is not coming any more. Also noticed that the exitValue is coming as `255`.

Comment: Check the error stream from `ProcessBuilder`.  What happens when you run the command on the command line?

Comment: I get the below output:                                                                    
                                                                                                           
`Scanning...Overall found 0 entries`

Comment: In the error stream I am getting this message `Usage: ./grep.pl [files to scan]
e.g. ./grep.pl /apps/ws/logs/*` which is a comment inside the script like `die "Usage: ./grep.pl [files to scan]\ne.g. ./grep.pl /apps/tkt-ws/logs/*" unless defined @ARGV;`

Comment: The `logs` directory is not empty and it will never be empty.

Comment: The command needs to be interpreted as a whole by the shell as shown in the update...